# Extending short key for AES256 (SNMPv3)

Tags: encryption, aes, snmp, sha

I am currently working on security of a switch that runs SNMPv3.

I am expected to code it in such a way, that any SHA (1 - 2-512) is compatible with any AES (128 - 256C).

Everything, like the algorithms alone, works pretty well. The problem is, that its been estabilished, that we are going to use SHA for key generation for both authentification and encryption.

When I want to use, let's say, SHA512 with AES256, there's no problem, since SHA has output of 64B and I need just 32B for key for AES256.

But when I want to use SHA1 with AES256, SHA1 produces only 20B, which is insufficient for the key.

I've searched the internet through and through and I found out, that it's common to use this combination (snmpget, openssl), but I havent found a single word about how are you supposed to prolong the key.

How can I extend the key from 20B to 32B so it works?

P. S.: Yes, I know SHA isn't KDF, yes, I know it's not that common to use this combination, but this is just how it is in my job assignment.

Comment: KDF's aren't magical and can use hash function like the SHAs, consider [RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869).

Comment: Yep, and that's basically the only cryptographic primitive it uses. So whatever you do, it **will** be a KDF. Now the question becomes do you want to create one yourself (bad) or will use use a standardized one (good). The most simple ones are called [KDF1 and KDF2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67280/1172), which simply extends the input with a counter, and then concatenates the output. It is theoretically not as secure as HKDF, but they haven't really been broken either.

Comment: You should however wonder why you'd want to couple a known insecure hash with AES-256.  And you should wonder why you posted this on [so] instead of [crypto.se] of course.

Comment: I wonder what exactly you are trying to implement. Can you go through the RFC document and point out which part of section 7 triggers this question? https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3414#section-7

Comment: @LexLi it's part 2.6 and connected implementation. My company uses precisely the algorithm shown in A.2.2 (modified by me a bit, so it works for all hashes). The problem arises, when I need a localized key for let's say AES192 for encryption while using SHA1 for authentification. If I understand correctly, there must be always used the same hash algorithm for both localized key generation and authentification. The result of SHA1 is always 20 octets, whereas I need 24 for AES192 and I am asking, how to extend the 20-octet key to 24 so it will be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://snmp.com/snmpv3/snmpv3_aes256.shtml) is a page discussing your exact question. In short, there is no standard way to do this (as you have already discovered), however, Cisco has adopted the approach outlined in section 2.1 of [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-reeder-snmpv3-usm-3desede-00.txt#section-2.1) document:

> Chaining is described as follows.  First, run the password-to-key algorithm with inputs of the passphrase and engineID as described in the USM document.  This will output as many key bits as the hash algorithm used to implement the password-to-key algorithm.  Secondly, run the password-to-key algorithm again with the previous output (instead of the passphrase) and the same engineID as inputs.  Repeat this process as many times as necessary in order to generate the minimum number of key bits for the chosen privacy protocol.  The outputs of each execution are concatenated into a single string of key bits.
>
> When this process results in more key bits than are necessary, only the most significant bits of the string should be used.
>
> For example, if password-to-key implemented with SHA creates a 40-octet string string for use as key bits, only the first 32 octets will be used for usm3DESEDEPrivProtocol.

Comment: Sample code can be found in various SNMP implementations, like [this in snmp4j](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/snmp4j/blob/352d70990567d67d7c52b83950953ec37d6d04cb/src/main/java/org/snmp4j/security/PrivAES.java#L197).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the thing I was looking for. It seems I am not able to use google search properly :D.